# jquery Set Table Row Focus

Tags: jquery

Trying to move focus to a specific table row based on user click.

```
<script>
   $(function(){
       $('.filter').click(function(){
           var id = $(this).attr('id');
           var row = "post_"+id;

           //alert(row) == post_1234

           $('#'+row).find('tr').focus();
       });
});
</script>

<table id='activity'>
   <tr id='1234' class='filter'><td>Some Data</td></tr>
   <tr id='1234' class='filter'><td>Some Data</td></tr>
   <tr id='1234' class='filter'><td>Some Data</td></tr>   
</table>

//Tons of data that scrolls down page quite a distance..

<table>
 <tr id='post_1234'><td>...</td></tr>
 <tr id='post_1235'><td>...</td></tr>
 <tr id='post_1236'><td>...</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have tried:

```
$('.filter').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var row = "post_"+id;

  //alert(row) == post_1234

  $('#'+row).find('tr').focus();
});
```

Does nothing

```
$('#'+row).focus();
```

Does nothing either.

The alert fires correctly with correct id shown.

as a test I did this:

```
 $('#'+row).find('td').addClass('someClass');
```

and it added the class correctly.

What am I missing?

Comment: edited question to include more info.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you need to find that in table as below or `focus` directly. I have changed focus to `CSS` to see the output.

```js
$('.filter').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var row = "post_" + id;
  console.log(row);
  // $("table").find($("#" + row).css("color", "red")); //Use this
  $("#" + row).css("color", "red"); //Or this
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='activity'>
  <tr id='1234' class='filter'>
    <td>Some Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='1234' class='filter'>
    <td>Some Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='1234' class='filter'>
    <td>Some Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr id='post_1234'>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='post_1235'>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='post_1236'>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ok, i just did the same thing. Instead of focus, i just added a class to change the background color. that worked fine. the "focus" fails, not the finding of the tr...

Comment: @bart2puck focus event is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form elements (<input>, <select>, etc.) and links (<a href>). Read more here https://api.jquery.com/focus/